# How do I write dynamic queries to implement this logic in plsql?

Tags: sql, plsql

Code goes like this-

```
If value = 1 then
logic1

elsif value = 2 then

logic1 + logic2

elsif value = 3 then

logic1 + logic2 + logic3.

endif;
```

Logic 1,2,3 has data from same table but columns are different. 
In case of logic1 -column1 is used, for logic2-column 2 etc.

How can I merge it to check value execute queries dynamically?
Like if value is 1 then it should only return value from logic 1 and skip other two. And if its 2 then logic 3 should be skipped.

Comment: Please edit your question and be more specific about what you're trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: It will depend completely on what `logic1`, `logic2` and `logic3` are. Could they be coded as three procedures, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use dynamic SQL statement like this example and adapt to your case if it is the kind of dynamic queries that you want.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE EmpCurTyp  IS REF CURSOR;
  v_emp_cursor    EmpCurTyp;
  emp_record      employees%ROWTYPE;
  v_stmt_str      VARCHAR2(200);
  v_e_job         employees.job%TYPE;
  value           valueTyp;
BEGIN
   value :=1; -- possibly may be a parameter

   -- Dynamic SQL statement with placeholder:

   If value=1 then

      v_stmt_logic1 := 'SELECT logic1-col1, logic1-col2, ... FROM employees   WHERE logic1-col1 = :j';

      -- Open cursor logic1 & specify bind variable in USING clause:
      OPEN v_logic1_cursor FOR v_stmt_str USING 'valueOflogic1';

   elsif value=2 then

      v_stmt_logic_12 := 'SELECT logic1-col1, logic1-col2, logic2-col1, logic2-col2, ... FROM employees   WHERE logic1-col1 = :j';

      -- Open cursor for logic1+2 & specify bind variable in USING clause:
      OPEN v_logic12_cursor FOR v_stmt_str USING 'valueOflogic12';

   elsif value=3 then

      v_stmt_logic_132 := 'SELECT * FROM employees   WHERE logic1-col1 = :j';

      -- Open cursor for all logics & specify bind variable in USING clause:
      OPEN v_logic123_cursor FOR v_stmt_str USING 'valueOflogic123';

  endif;      

  -- Fetch rows from result set one at a time:
  LOOP
    FETCH v_emp_cursor INTO emp_record;
    EXIT WHEN v_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;

  -- Close cursor:
  CLOSE v_emp_cursor;
END;
```

That is only one idea that I think that you want and I try to show you an example using pl/sql dinamic native queries.